# Java iterate over String where "characters" can have a span greater than 1

Tags: java, string, unicode, character-encoding, cjk

I have a string that I would like to iterate over and extract the "characters". However, this string is in Japanese and some of the "characters" span the length of two characters instead of one.

For example "" is a string that has length 4. The Unicode characters each span the length of 2 chars.

How can I extract each substring that represents a word from this string? In this case, String.charAt(int i) will not work.

Comment: `Character.codePointAt()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java charAt used with characters that have two code units](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14150530/java-charat-used-with-characters-that-have-two-code-units)

Comment: @AniketSahrawat: `String` also has a `codePointAt()` method. Also look at `String.offsetByCodePoints()`.

Comment: The distinction between UTF-16 code unit and [Unicode](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) codepoint isn't just relevant to certain script blocks, but also to modern text in general. For example,    music,  mathematics,  symbols,  emoticons, …, …,…  .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to correctly compute the length of a String in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6828076/how-to-correctly-compute-the-length-of-a-string-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your locale is not configured for the character set you are using.  See this link for setting the correct locale and examples.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/locale/create.html