# How to pad Strings with Unicode characters in Java

Tags: java, unicode, text-formatting

I add right padding to a String to output it in a table format.

```
for (String[] tuple : testData) {
  System.out.format("%-32s -> %s\n", tuple[0], tuple[1]);
}
```

The result looks like this (random test data):

```
znZfmOEQ0Gb68taaNU6HY21lvo       -> Xq2aGqLedQnTSXg6wmBNDVb
frKweMCH8Kvgyk0J                 -> lHJ5r7YDV0jTL
NxtHP                            -> odvPJklwIzZZ
NX2scXjl5dxWmer                  -> wPDlKCKllVKk
x2HKsSHCqDQ                      -> RMuWLZ2vaP9sOF0yHmjVysJ
b0hryXKd6b80xAI                  -> 05MHjvTOxlxq1bvQ8RGe
```

This approach does not work when there are multi-byte unicode characters:

```
0OZotivbyGhZM1FIwNhn6r6cC -> OKDxDV1o2NMqXH3VvE7q3uONwEcY5V
fBHRCjU4K8OCdzACmQZSn6WO         -> gvGBtUO5a4gPMKj9BKqBHFKx1iO7
cDUhb0cXkLWkS                -> SZX
WtP9t                            -> Q0wWOeY3W66mM5rcQQYKpG
va4du8SS                       -> KI
a71?⚖TZ‍♀ws5J              -> b8A
```

As you can see, the alignment is off.

My idea was to calculate the difference between the length of the String and the number of bytes used and use that to offset the padding, something like this:

```
int correction = tuple[0].getBytes().length - tuple[0].length();
```

And then instead of padding to 32 chars, I would pad to `32 + correction`. However, this didn't work either.

Here is my test code (using [emoji-java](https://github.com/vdurmont/emoji-java) but the behaviour should be reproducable with any unicode characters):

```
import java.util.Collection;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils;
import com.vdurmont.emoji.Emoji;
import com.vdurmont.emoji.EmojiManager;

public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // create random test data
    String[][] testData = new String[15][2];
    for (String[] tuple : testData) {
      tuple[0] = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(2, 32);
      tuple[1] = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(2, 32);
    }

    // add some emojis
    Collection<Emoji> all = EmojiManager.getAll();
    for (String[] tuple : testData) {
      for (int i = 1; i < tuple[0].length(); i++) {
        if (Math.random() > 0.90) {
          Emoji emoji = all.stream().skip((int) (all.size() * Math.random())).findFirst().get();
          tuple[0] = tuple[0].substring(0, i - 1) + emoji.getUnicode() + tuple[0].substring(i + 1);
        }
      }
    }

    // output
    for (String[] tuple : testData) {
      System.out.format("%-32s -> %s\n", tuple[0], tuple[1]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to correctly compute the length of a String in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6828076/how-to-correctly-compute-the-length-of-a-string-in-java)

Comment: Thanks, it gives some context but I'm still not able to solve my specific problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are actually a few issues here, other than that some fonts display the flag wider than the other characters. I assume that you want to count the Chinese flag as a single character (as it is drawn as a single element on the screen).

#### The String class reports an incorrect length

The String class works with `char`s, which are 16-bit integers of Unicode code points. The problem is that not all code points fit in 16 bits, only code points from the Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP) fit in those `char`s. `String`'s `length()` method returns the number of `char`s, not the number of code points.

Now `String`'s `codePointCount` method may help in this case: it counts the number of code points in the given index range. So providing `string.length()` as second argument to the method returns the total count of code points.

#### Combining characters

However, there's another problem. The  Chinese flag, for example, consists of *two Unicode code points*: the Regional Indicator Symbol Letters C (, U+1F1E8) and N (, U+1F1F3). Those two code points are combined into a flag of China. This is a problem you are not going to solve with the `codePointCount` method.

The Regional Indicator Symbol Letters [*seem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regional_indicator_symbol) to be a special occasion. Two of those characters can be combined into a national flag. I am not aware of a standard way to achieve what you want. You may have to take that manually into account.

I've written a small program to get the length of a string.

```java
static int length(String str) {
    String a = "\uD83C\uDDE6";
    String z = "\uD83C\uDDFF";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[" + a + "-" + z + "]{2}");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
    int count = 0;
    while (m.find()) {
        count++;
    }
    return str.codePointCount(0, str.length()) - count;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As is discussed by the comments in the question linked to by @Xehpuk, in [this discussion](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/string-padend-length-int-and-multi-code-point-characters/16138/3) on kotlinlang.org as well as in this blog post by [Daniel Lemire](https://lemire.me/blog/2018/06/15/emojis-java-and-strings/) the following seems to be correct:

> The problem is that the java String class represents characters as
> UTF-16 characters. This means any unicode character that is
> represented by more than 16 bits is saved as 2 separate Char values.
> This fact is ignored by many of the functions within String, eg.
> String.lenght does not return the number of unicode characters, it
> returns the number of 16bit characters within the String, some emoji
> counting for 2 characters.

The behaviour, however, seems to be implementation-specific.

As David mentions in his post you could try the following to get the correct lenght:

```
tuple.codePointCount(0, tuple.length())
```

See [code point methods](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#codePointCount(int,int)) from Java SE docs