# How to count the number of string characters in Kotlin?

Tags: android, string, kotlin

```
@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
private fun countName(x: String) {
    val textView: TextView = findViewById(R.id.result)
    for (i in 0 until x.length) {
        textView.text = i.toString()
    }
}
```

This is what I have so far. It works somewhat but for some reason it is lagging behind 1 number. For example, if I type `James`, the number it will output would be 4.

Comment: so then +1 to your result. your for starts at 0

Comment: This logic doesn't really make sense, just setting `textView.text  = x.length.toString()` would be identical, there's no need for a loop.

Comment: Instead of you having to use a for loop, why don't you just use `textView.text = x.length.toString()`???

Comment: You don't need the loop, but the reason this isn't working is because ``x until y`` defines an range that **doesn't include** ``y`` - it's everything *up to* that value, which is why for "James" (length 5) the last loop you do is ``i == 4``. If you want an **inclusive** range (that includes the last value) you need to do ``x .. y``

Answer (score 1):

How to get the number of characters in a string (usually what you want):

```kotlin
str.length
```

How to get the number of Unicode code points in a string (because sometimes a code point is encoded as multiple characters):

```kotlin
str.codePointCount(0, str.length)
```

See [this Java answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6828179/208273) for more details on the difference between these two options.

Comment: (Also please let me know if this question is actually a duplicate of some Kotlin string length question.  I couldn't find one when I looked.)

Answer (score 0):

There are many simple ways to get the number of characters in a string. but if you want to know the mistake in your code you should have started to count from 1 instead of 0.

```
for (i in 1 until x.length) {
        textView.text = i.toString()
    }
```